# SQL generated by Hibernate invalid for MS SQL

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

Hibernate (HQL) generated the following SQL for which I inserted the parameters:

```
select 
sum(activity0_.calculated_work) as col_0_0_
, employee2_.id as col_1_0_
, projectele1_.id as col_2_0_ 

from 
activity activity0_ 
inner join generic_object activity0_1_ on activity0_.id=activity0_1_.id 
left outer join project_element projectele1_ on     activity0_.project_element_id=projectele1_.id 
left outer join employee employee2_ on activity0_.owner_id=employee2_.id 
left outer join org_unit orgunit3_ on employee2_.org_unit_id=orgunit3_.id 

where 
activity0_1_.deleted=0 and 
activity0_.client_id=22 

 group by 
 employee2_.id order by SUM(activity0_.calculated_work) DESC
```

Error message: Column 'project_element.id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I executed this SQL directly in the SQL Server Studio with the same result. I commented this line:

```
, projectele1_.id as col_2_0_
```

The SQL was then accepted by the SQL Server

The table project_element definitely has a column with the name id it is also referenced in the LEFT OUTER JOIN and there this column is not causing an error.

Removing the alias projectele1_ had no effect.

To me this looks like a really simple SQL statement. I cannot imagine what is wrong with it and the error message is not helping at all. Any ideas what could be wrong with the SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your SQL syntax is wrong.If you add `projectele1_.id` to group by clause it will work.Only aggregate functions work in select statement with group by clause.Or if you remove `projectele1_.id` from select it will work fine.

Comment: Do you happen to know whether that is SQL standard? MySQL does support the statement and Hibernate does not generate a SQL which is supported by MS SQL which was unexpected to me.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake. I should have read the error message several times. `projectele1_id` is not in the `group by` clause. MS SQL does not allow to include such a column into the select list. This seems to be a consistency check.
Too bad though that the usage of HQL leads to such an exception in SQL Server but not in MySQL Server.